# Convert binary data received as string to Google Drive blob

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, blob

In my Google Apps Script web app,

I am trying to upload an excel file to google drive using a post request received on the web app.

I don't have much control over the way the excel file is sent.

It is currently being sent in a raw format like this :

```
PKj7VN?Ȗ[Content_Types].xml???N?0E???NY ??tQ`   H?0?$???iI??)B?EW~?;sfFSm'??BT??t?JJ?J?*???c?\??mS?O"IVk: ?Σ??Ȝ???#0=CϽ???ߖ???"X,p?A??:q?H????`?H?n1ά?
ﵒ?Ώ??C)??"?'?Ǜd?|?0+???4??Z?W%?딄?ɃI!,?????ɌP6?F?D?aRV>i??????Ȯ?Ǔ???^??????R?Y?<?+N`?wi?????S??|PKj7V???_rels/.rels??A?0D????]c(l?   [???Sh?V??ۥ.'3?&S5???C4?l?:E?qZ??;o???g?r"??G?+.
S?GΣ??X?G?????)ˠ??j???,?<|2`?d???e?O
```

How do I convert this string to a blob and upload it to google drive. What I have tried is this :

```
function doPost(e) {
  var binaryData = e.postData.contents //string
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(binaryData,'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', "myExcelFile.xlsx"));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("File uploaded successfully!");
}
```

The file did get uploaded but it's corrupt and not viewable.

Edit :

I am able to accomplish this on local machine using python but not able to replicate it on google apps script.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import io
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/save', methods=['POST'])
def save_to_excel():
    # Get the raw request data
    data = request.data
    print(type(data)) #<class 'bytes'>
    toread = io.BytesIO()
    toread.write(data)
    toread.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_excel(toread)
    file_name = 'sampleData.xlsx'
    df.to_excel(file_name)
    # Create a new Excel workbook
    return "Data saved as xlsx file: {}"
```

Comment: can you export the excel file to CSV and upload that? that will be a much easier method

Comment: I think that in this case, it is difficult to correctly convert your showing data as the correct XLSX data. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot know the detail of `a post request received on the web app.`. But, in this case, how about checking the script for uploading the XLSX data of your Web Apps?

Comment: @ACarter The CSV sent from the same source doesn't have as much information as the excel file. Example: It doesn't include headers, many null cells in the wrong places, etc.

Comment: @Tanaike The source of this data is a Tally Erp Export feature which can't be tweaked much without implementing a custom extension. A post request received on the web app is an export request sent by tally to Google Apps Script Web App. The request contains raw bytes. But when received by the web app it's converting it into a string.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand `a post request received on the web app.` from your reply. In your question, can you provide the detailed method and script for requesting your Web Apps with the POST method?

Comment: Thanks, `a post request received on the web app` means that I am sending an HTTP POST request to a google apps script deployed as a web app. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I am sending an HTTP POST request to a google apps script deployed as a web app.`, can you provide the detailed method for running this?